# how to go to next activity after ViewPager in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-viewpager

I created a "Slide Image" in first activity; which has five images. After I slide the last image(fifth), it should go to next activity,say-activity_next.xml.

Below is my code to slide Image i.e., SlideActivity.java

```
public class SlideActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
         ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
         viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);  

    }

     private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
            private int[] mImages = new int[] {
                R.drawable.one,
                R.drawable.two,
                R.drawable.three,
                R.drawable.four,
                R.drawable.five
            };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return mImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

     @Override
     public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
       Context context = Illustrations.this;
       ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
       int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
              R.dimen.padding_medium);
       imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
       imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
       imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
       ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
       return imageView;
      }

}
}
```

I'm not getting where to pass Intent for next activity i.e., `activity_next.xml`

**** UPDATED CODE as per your suggestions ****

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
     ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
     viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);  



  viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(position==viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()){
    Intent reg = new Intent(SlideActivity.this,activity_next.class);
                startActivity(reg);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


    }

        private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private int[] mImages = new int[] {
            R.drawable.one,
            R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.three,
            R.drawable.four,
            R.drawable.five
        };

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
      return mImages.length+1;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
       }

         @Override
     public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
     Context context = Illustrations.this;
     ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
     int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
          R.dimen.padding_medium);
     imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
     imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
     if(position < getCount()-1)
     imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
     ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
     return imageView;
   }




    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object   object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
 }
 }
```

****activity_next.java code is below ****

```
public class activity_next extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);
}

}
```

**** activity_next.xml code is as below****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome to Nowhere Else" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In " Intent reg = new Intent(Activity_Next.this,activity_next.class);" What is your Activity_Next.this ?

Comment: Sory that was a mistake. I have updated that code. Plz check it nw.

Comment: It is strange that you have blank activity... It should work, try to change the textView1 text color to be sure

Comment: I changed color also.Its not going to next intent i.e., next activity. After I slide the last image blank white screen is coming.

Comment: Oh it is not launching the activity? Maybe here : position==viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()        position will start to 0, so you should put : position==(viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() -1)

Comment: Great brother.. Thank u very much.. I got it to next activity... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it clear as @Chol said I just made the count to -1 as below.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if(position==viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()-1){
                Intent reg = new   
 Intent(Illustrations.this,Register_Page.class);
                startActivity(reg);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


     });

  }
```

Thank you all very much ... :)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not getting where to pass Intent for next activity i.e.,
>   activity_next.xml

To start Activity on reach of last item in ViewPager add `OnPageChangeListener` to ViewPager and in `onPageSelected` start next Activity:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPageSelected(int position) 
     {     
            if(position==viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()){
                //start next Activity here with activity_next.xml layout
             }
     } 
     ....
});
```

Comment: i went with same logic. first, `setOnPageChangeListener` is deprecated. i guess you should use `addOnPageChangeListener` instead. also, in this case your `//start next Activity here with activity_next.xml layout` line will be called right after the last page is centered on screen. i was trying to add another control into the same code.

Comment: I did this, after the fifth image i'm getting blank activity

Comment: btw, i was using `onPageScrolled` method in listener. and i just realized that position should never be equal to count. am i wrong?

Comment: I just used addOnPageChangeListener but again the same, after my fifth image when i slide its displaying blank activity.

Comment: @Kirataka: onPageSelected method and you are saying getting blank Activity? so please share updated code

Comment: @Kirataka: as you are saying getting Blank Activity . then what is issue ? because as in question you are not going to next Activity on last page of ViewPager . but now u are able to see blank Activity. is any other data which u need to show in next Activity?

Comment: @iamkaan i'm moving images by sliding it.. not scrolling.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I need to go to next activity i.e., activity_next.xml.  after i swipe the last image, what i'm getting is the blank screen. I have some contents in the activity_next.xml, contents are not displaying in that activity_next.xml

Comment: @Kirataka: Please show `activity_next.class` class code. have u added `activity_next.class` class in AndroidManifast.xml ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes i added it in AndroidManifast.xml.
Please find the activity_next.class & activity_next.xml code above

Answer (score 2):

If you want to slide the last image to go to the next Activity, like a "dismiss" efect, you should try something like this:

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] mImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three,
        R.drawable.four,
        R.drawable.five
    };

@Override
public int getCount() {
  return mImages.length+1;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
   return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
   Context context = Illustrations.this;
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
   int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
      R.dimen.padding_medium);
   imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
   imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
if(position < getCount()-1)
   imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
   ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
   return imageView;
}
```

and then:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
     ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
     viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
     viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) 
        {     
            if(position==viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()-1){
            //start next Activity
            }
        } 
     });  

}
```

Comment: I'm getting blank activity after the fifth image... :(

Comment: If you start your next activity on method "onPageSelected", when you slide after the 5th page, a new activity should start, with the layout you set. Can you show your code to start the new activity?

Comment: First, your classes should start with a capital letter "Activity_next", and should be camel case -> ActivityNext. I think the problem could be on the context you are using to start new activity. You are using Illustrations.this, you should use SlideActivity.this

Comment: Its `Activity_Next.class` and `activity_next.xml`. U really think this is the problem?

Comment: When you say that the activity is blank, you mean a real new Activity, or a blank 6th slide?

Comment: I need a real new activity not blank 6th slide. But i think i'm getting the blank 6th slide.

Comment: Hm.. ok. Can you debug to be sure that method onPageSelected is being called? I'm afraid that for some reason this method is not being called.

Comment: Got it bro... As Chol said above..
It should be: position==(viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() -1)

Thank u for ur support

Answer (score 1):

**The position is image's position that comes array like slide_image[position]. So, with using position, the Intent can be create at the SliderAdapter page just writing several code.**

@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {

```
    layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
    LinearLayout layoutslide = view.findViewById(R.id.slider);

    ImageView slideImageView =(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.slide_image);
    TextView slideHeading=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.slide_heading);
    TextView slideDescription=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.slide_desc);

    slideImageView.setImageResource(slide_image[position]);
    slideHeading.setText(slide_headings[position]);
    slideDescription.setText(slide_description[position]);

    slideImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (position == 0) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,EarthQuakeActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
            }
            if (position == 1) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,EarthQuakeActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
            }

            if (position == 2) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context,EarthQuakeActivity.class);
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
            }


        }
    });
```